# Relationships between nodes are not created or updated

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 types of nodes in my database: BOOK and WRITTER.

The two nodes has the id property named 'id':

```
{
  "identity": 20220,
  "labels": [
    "WRITTER"
  ],
  "properties": {
"title": "Eliott",
"id": "Eliott"
  }
}

{
  "identity": 1,
  "labels": [
    "BOOK"
  ],
  "properties": {
"title_book": "book_1",
"id": 2
  }
}
```

I would like to have the relationships between them. I have a dataframe where each row represent the source_id(WRITTER nodes) and the target_id(BOOK nodes).

The dataframe df_relationships looks like this:

```
bookid writterid
1      'James'
2      'Eliott'
```

I tried this but nothing is happening:

```
request = """
UNWIND $data as row
MATCH (b:BOOK), (w:WRITTER)
WHERE b.id = row.bookid AND w.id= row.writterid
MERGE (w)-[:HAS_WRITTEN]->(b)
"""
params = list()
for i, row in df_relationships.iterrows():
    params.append({'id':row.bookid, 'id':row.writterid})
    if i % 5000 == 0:
        session.run(request , {'data':params})
        params = []
session.run(request , {'data':params})
```

I see no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` only has the key `id` but yet you lookup `bookid` and `writterid` in the cypher. Maybe try,

```
params.append({'bookid':row.bookid, 'writterid':row.writterid})
```

Comment: Thank you @aldrin, it was one of the mistakes I made. I changed this too:

'UNWIND $data as row
MATCH (b:BOOK), (w:WRITTER)
WHERE same as above
MERGE same as above'

Answer (score 0):

try to use create it will create relationship

```
CREATE (w)-[:HAS_WRITTEN]->(b)
```

Comment: `MERGE` creates the pattern if it doesn't exists, so `MERGE` is fine here

Comment: `WHERE b.id = row.bookid AND w.id= row.writterid`
replace this one to
`WHERE ID(b) = row.bookid AND ID(w) = row.writterid`